# Pass a NAN in input vector for prediction

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a classifier that has been trained using a given set of input training data vectors. There are missing values in the training data which is filled as numpy.Nan values and Using imputers to fill in the missing values.

However, In case of my input vector for prediction, how do I pass in the input where the value is missing? should I pass the value as nan? Does imputer play a role in this.?

If I have to fill in the value manually, How do I fill in the value for such case will I need to calculate the mean/median/frequency from the existing data.

Note : I am using sklearn.

Comment: Process (that is impute values) your input just as you processed your tain set.

Comment: Suppose I have a single input vector and how would the imputer strategy work? How will i find the mean/median/frequency?

Comment: No you can only do that when you have a batch of samples ( at least two ).
Don't use this sample if it's missing, or train a regressor on your training set to predict the value of the feature missing, then predict it the missing value using this regressor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use NaN values because the input vector will, for instance, be multiplied with a weight matrix. The result of such operations needs to be defined.

What you typically do if you have gaps in your input data is, depending on the specific type and structure of the data, fill the gaps with "artificial" values. For instance, you can use the mean or median of the same column in the remaining training data instances.